# Could not insert new outlet collection Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9-beta5

I am currently using the new Xcode Version 9 Beta 5 and Swift 4. I tried to start a new application using the "Single View Application" (it did not automatically come with a View Controller File, only the usual Info.plist, Main storyboard, Assets xcassets, LaunchScreen.storyboard)

As there is no View Controller file, I created one and tried to segue an image view but I got the error below instead.

[image: The error message that appeared]

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Main.storyboard,
2. Select the View Controller,
3. Open the Identity Inspector,
4. In the class, choose the ViewController.swift file you created.
   Then try again creating the outlet

[image]